# Need a word that describes a biweekly publication

Tags: word-choice

Our company publishes an internal e-newsletter that we call the <Title> Weekly. We're now going to publish every other week, so the title needs to be changed. The first solution that came to mind was <Title> Biweekly, but a few questions on this site have pointed out that "biweekly" is a troublesome word, and we didn't really like the word anyways.

What is a good word to describe a publication that is now publishing less than it used to? Searching around on this site yielded "fortnightly" as an idea, but that doesn't fly as well across the pond. I just learned about the existence of "hebdomadal", but I doubt that "bihebdomadal" would get approved.

Any ideas? It doesn't even have to be a synonym of biweekly; in fact, it'd probably be better if we went in another direction. The publication is publishing less frequently so the idea of scaling back could be in play, but the new format opens the door for a more focused and relevant publication, because we won't be struggling for content week after week. So, a word like "condensed" could be on the table as well. Or, even a word that's better than "regular" to indicate that while it's not as frequent, it's still a regular publication.

Comment: If you don’t know how often it will be published, it’s hard to see how any one word can describe such irregularity. Hadn't you better just stick with <Title>?

Comment: We know it'll be every other week now. Just &lt;Title&gt; is an option, but certainly not the best.

Comment: How about *occasional*?

Comment: Hmm...occasional makes it sound intermittent, but we've done well with keeping a regular schedule.

Comment: Just call it a periodical.

Comment: *Digest* might work if you're focusing and condensing information.

Comment: I think it might help if you described the typical content in a bit more detail. Other than that I'd kinda go with *The <Title> Fortnight* or, if the typical content is kind of geeky/nerdy *The <Title> Month/2*

Comment: You could change the name from  “<Title> Weekly” to “<Title> Strongly”.

Comment: @Magnus Just an internal corporate newsletter: birthdays, anniversaries, sales tips, industry news, etc. I like month/2, but I don't know I could get that through :) Spiceyokooko and Kris, I like your words!

Comment: @Lidsacae yeah I do see how that could get kind of hard to get past the average management types ;). spiceyokooko's *Digest* sounds pretty good though, must've missed that earlier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Periodical* has the two senses you are looking for; but why not call it the *Personnel Clarion* or the *Coding Bugle*? The newsletter in one of my jobs, most of which informed us of things management should have told us but forgot, was called *The Caret*.

Comment: Wow, I like those suggestions! Wish I could upvote :)

Comment: Personally I love *The Caret*. It's... perfect :)

Comment: @Lidsacae: thanks for the thought. If, after a few days, you still like this answer best, you could accept it (click the tick on the left).

Comment: The student newspaper at my sister's high school was *The Hyperion* - nothing funny about that, right?  The inside joke, however, was that the staff had named it after [L.A's main wastewater-treatment plant](http://www.lasewers.org/treatment_plants/hyperion/index.htm)...

Answer (score 3):

I would think a form of "opportunist" would work well. It connotates the idea that it is published at exactly the right times and possibly contains information that would prove valuable to those searching for opportunity.

Comment: I like the idea that you're trying to convey, but 'opportunism' usually carries a negative connotation, no?

Answer (score 1):

[Semimonthly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/semimonthly) works:

> Occurring or issued twice a month.
>   A semimonthly publication.

Answer (score -2):

Fortnightly is the word you are looking for.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @ATG. 
Nice to see you here. While I agree with your answer, answers are nearly always better when they contain a link or two to sources. In this case a dictionary definition would suffice. Check out [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/).

Comment: The asker has already dismissed the word *fortnightly* in their question. Why should they change their mind?